# extending PDO as CodeIgniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I know CI 2.1.3 is now support PDO. but it'll more comfortable for me using pdo functions instead of codeigniter function, and Now I want to extend PDO and use it as library and create PDO object once it loaded by Controller or another library; It is possible, isn't it?, my attempt so far:

```
class Mypdo extends PDO {
  public function __construct($dsn='mysql:dbname=mydbname;host=localhost',
                              $username='myusername',
                              $password='mypassword',
                              $driver_options=array()) {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options);
  }
}
```

and simple usage:

```
class Otherlibrary{
   var $CI;
   var $something_id;

   public function __construct(){
      $this->CI =& get_instance();
      $this->CI->load->library('mypdo');

      $this->something_id = 'foo';
   }

   public function is_something_exist(){
      try{
         $q = "SELECT * FROM something WHERE something_id = '$this->something_id'";
         $stmt = $this->CI->mypdo->prepare($q); //<--PROBLEM
         $stmt->execute();

         if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1){
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
       } catch (PDOException $e){
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
    }
}
```

always return:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in...

I'm not expert at all in PHP class/object, so please I need help to improve my code and make it works. Thanks.

Comment: i think it have active records

Comment: @ArunKillu I dont understand, how does active records matter? what should I do?

Comment: why you want again to implement pdo when the framework itself provide one.http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: @ArunKillu I just feel more comfortable using PDO function instead of using CI's one.

Comment: Where is your Mypdo file located and what is the name of it?

Comment: I would turn on log_threshold to 1 in config.php and see if there is an error when codeigniter is trying to instantiate that class

Comment: @J.Money my file is in application/library named mypdo.php

Comment: It needs to be called Mypdo.php with a capital M for codeigniter to be able to load it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the CodeIgniter [Libraries documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html):

- File names must be capitalized. For example:  Myclass.php Class
- declarations must be capitalized. For example:  class Myclass
- Class names and file names must match.

Make sure that your Mypdo class is application/library/Mypdo.php.

Comment: thanks, my class loaded correctly, I test it by change my connection password and then it return PDO error; But my problem actually is passing that connection to another class function;

Comment: If that library is being loaded into an instance of CI then you should be able to access it anywhere. What is the symptoms now?